# Defining a cell inside Google Sheets using a Script

Tags: google-sheets

I am writing a Google Sheets Script to save as Sheet file to a PDF. I want the File Name to be `Cell A11` (which is a combination of texts from other cells). So I wrote this:

```
file.setName(Cell + '.pdf');
```

My question is: how can I define "Cell" to pull data from A11 from inside the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. Add this function to your script.

```
function getFilename() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    // Edit the sheet name as necessary

    var cell = sheet.getRange('A11');
    var filename = cell.getValue();

    return filename;
}
```

Then change

`file.setName(Cell + '.pdf');`

to

`file.setName(getFilename() + '.pdf');`